# Return a value in Blocking.get in Ratpack

Tags: java, ratpack

How can I return an object or list after using `Blocking.get()` method in Ratpack?

```
Blocking.get(()->
            xRepository.findAvailable()).then(x->x.stream().findFirst().get());
```

Above line returns void - I want to be able to do something like below so that it returns the object in the then clause. I tried adding a return statement but doesn't work.

```
Object x = Blocking.get(()->
            xRepository.findAvailable()).then(x->x.stream().findFirst().get());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map to work with the value when it's available.

```
Blocking.get(() -> xRepository.findAvailable())
         .map(x -> x.stream().findFirst().get())
         .then(firstAvailable -> ctx.render("Here is the first available x " + firstAvailable))
```

Ratpack's [`Promise<T>`](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/exec/Promise.html) does not provide blocking operation like `Promise.get()` that blocks current thread and returns a result. Instead you have to subscribe to the promise object. One of the methods you can use is [`Promise.then(Action<? super T> then)`](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/exec/Promise.html#then-ratpack.func.Action-) which allows you to specify and action that will be triggered when given value is available. In above example we use `ctx.render()` as an action triggered when value from blocking operation is ready, but you can do other things as well.

Comment: how can i return the object retrieved in the then clause - I dont want to do ctx.render